# How to get rid of JpaRepository interfaces in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

How do I avoid having a class and an interface per entity when using JPA with Spring Boot?

I have the following entity (and 10 other):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
  private String username;

  @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
  private String password;

  ...
```

In order to be able to persist this entity, I need to setup an interface per entity:

```
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {
}
```

and then `@autowire` it:

```
@Controller
public class AdminController {

  @Autowired
  AccountRepository accountRepo;

  Account account = new Account();
  account.setUsername(...);
  ...
  accountRepo.save(account);
```

If I now have 10 entities, it means that I need to define 10 `@Repository` interfaces and `@autowire` each of those 10 interfaces.

How would I embed that save method directly into `Account` so that I only have to call `account.save()` and how do I get rid of all those `@repository` interfaces I have to declare per entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely not the answer you like, but I give it to you anyways.
All this interfaces per class seems useless and boilerplate when starting a project, but this changes over time when a project gets larger. There are more and more custom database interactions per entity. Additionally you can also define queries for a group of entities by subclassing the JpaRepository class.

But it is possible to improve the controller sections of your code by declaring a base class handling the repository autowire.

Example how this could be done (requires I think Spring 4)

```
public class BaseController<Model> {

    @Autowired
    protected JpaRepository<Model, Long> repository;

}

@Controller
public class AdminController extends BaseController<Admin> {

}
```

Comment: Might even be worth going through the effort to setup all the Hibernate boilerplate manually and having the entityManager injected into the Entity by AspectJ, but all that defeats the purpose of using SpringBoot as a rapid dev tool. BaseController is already an improvement.

Comment: In general there are at least two large patterns. One is the repository pattern and the other one is the active record pattern. Spring Data follows the repository pattern approach so choosing Spring Data does most likely mean you have to go with it. On the other side grails gorm is different, since it is using the active record pattern. This allows to interact with the database via the domain object (which is what you mean). So its a choice of the technology you want to use for your project.

Comment: Awesome, so it comes down to Active Record Pattern VS Repository Pattern. I'll need to do a bit of reading on when to choose the one pattern over the other pattern. Seems the Repository Pattern is better for complex business logic.

Answer (score 1):

One option, if your entities have some kind of relationship is to use `@OneToMany`, `@OneToOne` and friends type annotations.  This won't effectively replace all repository interfaces, but might reduce the amount you need.  Barring that, you could try the active record pattern.  Spring has Spring Roo that has some code generators for this, but I'm admittedly not a big fan of Roo.  A quick Google search turned up ActiveJPA which uses the active record style and gives you the benefits you're looking for without the need for Spring Roo, just doesn't look like it's been maintained in a while.  https://github.com/ActiveJpa/activejpa

Comment: I've just moved away from Spring Roo to Spring Boot, Spring Roo generates a crapload of AspecJ files most of which I never use, then I have to do Push In refactoring to get rid of all the AspectJ files. What I do like about its generated classes is that it injects an EntityManager making it possible to do `entity.persist()`, `entity.merge()`, etc. That's kinda what I'm after in Spring Boot - the convenience of Spring Boot minus the bloat.
`@OneToMany` I use frequently, thanks for the tip! I'm going to keep the question open for a few more days to see if I get other responses.